# Python Fibonnaci help - a, b = b, a + b

Tags: python, sequence

Hi i'm currently doing a research project and have one question.

This is the code i have

```
def mystery(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print (a)
        a, b = b, a + b


mystery(1000)
```

can someone give me a clear answer on how line 5 works `(a, b = b, a + b)` i just cant get my head around it, thank you in advance!

Comment: Python evaluates the right-hand expression as a tuple and unpacks it during assignment.

Comment: @RNar: True!  Thanks!

Comment: @user1836587 no, it print the fibonacci numbers under 1000

Comment: I thought it prints all the fibo sequence before it can pass 1000 so the last number would be 987

Comment: I was going to say that `fib(n)` defined to return the _nth_ number in the fibonnacci sequence in this way is _O_(_n_ ), while Abelson has a sweet algorithm that is  _O_ (log _n_ ).

Have to think about `n` vs `fib(n)`.

Comment: @user1836587 Since the sequence is a linear recurrence, that is it can be solved in closed form, you can solve this in `O(1)` (if you count exponentiation as constant-time operation, otherwise it is indeed `logn`  if you use exponentiation by squaring; note that this estimate doesn't take number multiplication complexity into account).

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yes.  The algorithm using squaring to calculate `exp(n)` is `O(log n)` in the number of multiplications required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line a, b = b, a + b does two things.

1. It assigns `a` the value of `b`;
2. It then assigns `a+b` to `b`using the original values of `a` and `b`, before the statement began to be executed.

Comment: "Using original values of a and b" would sound clearer

Comment: If it used the original values how would it make the fibo sequence?

Comment: @joevyso Original = before reassignment